# Xamarin iOS - Firebase Analytics is not available

Tags: xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

I have download the example project and library from this link: [Xamarin Firebase](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseiosanalytics/true) but after 2 days of configuration i get this error when i launch the app:

> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000022] Firebase Analytics is not available.

I did not find documentation related to this error for Xamarin iOS Firebase Analytics and can not find a solution.

I have reference the same library of the example project, checked the *GoogleService-Info.plist* and insert it in the project as documentation, called the `App.Configure ();`.

Nothing to do, does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolved!

Firebase Analytics requires 3 references to work:

1. .Core
2. .Analytics
3. .IstanceID

Following only the code in the documentation the project at start-up load only *.Core* skipping the other two, this causes the error.

To work around this problem, I added in *AppDelegate*:

```
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Firebase.InstanceID;
```

and before of `App.Configure ();` i have add this two line to force the app to load the two assemblies:

```
Firebase.Analytics.Loader loader1 = new Firebase.Analytics.Loader();
Firebase.InstanceID.Loader loader2 = new Firebase.InstanceID.Loader();
```

Of course, if you implement other instructions later using these two assemblies, you will not need these two instructions.

Comment: Man, you made my day! Thanks a lot! :)
Seems quite strange to me that those two assemblies are not loaded automatically during the app' startup.
Maybe you need to report your findings Xamarin.Firebase team?