# Xamarin Forms iOS - Assertion failure in firebaseFirebase Analytics

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, firebase-analytics

After setting up Firebase Analytics on both iOS and Android using DependencyService and then following the steps on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774378/firebase-analytics-in-xamarin-forms) to fix some bugs and using more supposed fixes on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541722/xamarin-ios-firebase-analytics-is-not-available), I'm still not able to setup Firebase on iOS.

It works fine on Android but on iOS the app just crashes while opening. This is the error I get:

```
[46244:5039010] *** Assertion failure in void _UIApplicationMainPreparations(int, char **, NSString *__strong, NSString *__strong)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.54.4/UIApplication.m:3924
```

Here's the iOS AppDelegate code:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        //XamForms.Controls.iOS.Calendar.Init();

        Firebase.Analytics.Loader loader1 = new Firebase.Analytics.Loader();
        Firebase.InstanceID.Loader loader2 = new Firebase.InstanceID.Loader();
        Firebase.Core.App.Configure();

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong? I can't even tell if it is a Forms, iOS or Nuget problem.